# Android Studio Arctic Fox Set testRunner as GRADLE instead of PLATFORM

Tags: android-studio, gradle, junit4, android-studio-arctic-fox

My JUnit 4 tests are failing after updating to Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3.

I noticed that it is creating a JUnit test configuration instead of Gradle test configuration when a test is run using the play button/icon near the test class or `@Test` method.

How to set the testRunner as GRADLE instead of PLATFORM in Android Studio Arctic Fox? There is no runner configuration found in Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle.

Or is there any way we can set this in the `build.gradle` file?

P.S. This is only for unit-tests and NOT for instrumentation tests.

Answer (score 1):

The GUI where to select the default runner isn't there anymore ..and I'm not sure if Android Studio would pick up `idea.properties`, but maybe in `gradle.properties` - or elsewhere, if it still exists:

```
idea.gradle.prefer.idea_test_runner=true
```